# CakePHP 2.5 HttpSocket Display Response

Tags: php, cakephp

This is my first time using this and im having issues. I have a HttpSocket->get which is working but i dont know how to display the results in my view

```
public function index() {

    $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
    // array query
    $results = $HttpSocket->get('https://myurl.com', array('username' => 'myuser','password'=>'mypassword','cmd'=>'mycommands'));
    //debug($results);
}
```

The response is there i can see it when i debug. please someone tell me how to show this in my view!!!

Thanks 
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP provide `set()` method to send variable value on view

```
$this->set("results", $results);
```

**Controller method** TestsController.php

```
public function index() {

    $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
    // array query
    $results = $HttpSocket->get('https://myurl.com', array('username' => 'myuser','password'=>'mypassword','cmd'=>'mycommands'));
    $this->set("results", $results);
    //debug($results);
}
```

For instance your controller name `TestsController` then you will create `file` `/view/Tests/index.ctp`

**view file index.ctp**

```
print_r($results);
```